# Can I change the order where python looks for a module first?

Tags: python, import

Imagine I have a script, let's say `my_tools.py` that I import as a module. But `my_tools.py` is saved twice: at `C:\Python27\Lib` 
and at the same directory from where the script is run that does the import.

Can I change the order where python looks for `my_tools.py` first? That is, to check first if it exists at `C:\Python27\Lib` and if so, do the import?

Comment: by default `import` will first look in current working dir, then move on to paths specified in `sys.path`

Comment: Yeah, I know. My question is: can change this?

Comment: Well, this is the use case: I have a script that I use privately with a different python version than other people on the network. So I want to be able to use a different version of the imported module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manipulate `sys.path` as much as you want... If you wanted to move the current directory to be scanned last, then just do `sys.path[1:] + sys.path[:1]`. Otherwise, if you want to get into the nitty gritty then the [imp module](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) can be used to customise until your hearts content - there's an example on that page, and one at http://blog.dowski.com/2008/07/31/customizing-the-python-import-system/

Answer (score 3):

You can modify [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path), which will determine the order and locations that Python searches for imports. (Note that you must do this *before* the import statement.)

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want python to search builtin modules then search in current folder first,,

you can change `sys.path`

`upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter`

`sys.path[0] is the empty string, which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first`, you can put this at the end of the list, that way it will first search in all possible location before coming to current directory