# name clash with app-name and local package name in django

Tags: python, django, name-clash

Suppose you have an app named 'foo'

and you are in the 'bar' app's subdirectory, e.g. my_site/bar/views/my_view.py.
From this file, you want to `from foo import a`.

Problem is, in that directory, you also have `foo.py` and import doesn't work.

Easy fix would be to change the `foo.py` file name, but is there other way around it?

Comment: Seems [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083026/can-i-change-the-order-where-python-looks-for-a-module-first) is one of the  options.